# How to provide a default size when the number of elements is unknown?

Tags: css

I would like to define a class applied to a `div` containing other `div` which would state that

- the display is CSS grid
- each column on that line should take `1fr`

This is easy when the number of elements is **known**:

```css
.line {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
}

.line div {
  border-style: dotted;
  border-width: 1px;
}
```

```html
<div class="line">
  <div>one</div>
  <div>two</div>
  <div>three</div>
</div>
```

**How to approach this when the number of elements is not known in advance?** Is there a way to tell "*each column will be `1fr`*" without an explicit number of repeats?

I thought that [`auto-fit` or `auto-fill`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/repeat) would do that, but apparently not.